# Does an NFT with a certain id exists? ERC1155

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, erc-1155

In Solidity, from inside a `ERC1155` contract, how does one find out whether or not a token with a certain `id` exists in this collection?

Will I have to create a variable to keep track of all the tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use or `uri()` function, which will fail it a token has not been minted yet. Otherwise you can utilize the [ERC1155Supply extention](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.9.1/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155Supply.sol), which gives you the `exists(id)` function.